# Remove Angularjs-Chart border and reduce chart arc thickness

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

How do i remove the border line of Angularjs doughnut chart and reduve the thickness of the arc.

HTML

```
            <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-colors="preColors" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverridePres" chart-dataset-options="preLegend" chart-data="preData" chart-labels="preName">
            </canvas>
```

JS

```
    $scope.preColors = ['#febe05','#f3f3f3'];
    $scope.preData = [343,78];
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code.

Comment: @Keno I have Updated the code

Comment: Did that work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed a bit your code (I think chart-dataset-options is incorrect) :

```
        <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" 
        chart-colors="preColors" 
        chart-options="preLegend" 
        chart-data="preData" 
        chart-labels="preName" 
        chart-dataset-override="preOverride">
        </canvas>
```

And The JS:

```
    $scope.preColors = ['#febe05', '#f3f3f3'];
    $scope.preData = [343, 78];
    $scope.preName = ['a', 'b'];

    $scope.preLegend = { 
      cutoutPercentage: 80, //arc thickness
      elements: {
        arc: {
          borderWidth: 0 // border line
        }
      }
    }
    $scope.preOverride = [{}];
```

Result:

[image]

Live demo: [SkinnyDoughnout](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/MbBZyQ?editors=0010)

Comment: thousand kisses on your cheeks

Comment: @keno thanks man you made my day and can we able to add  pin images for start and end of yellow circle ,its possible?